# Set TIFF's location creating raster with GRASS

Tags: grass-gis

I'm trying to create a raster with GRASS using the command r.in.gdal input="landsat-image.tiff" output="landsat-image.output" but I am getting this error:

```
Locação PROJ_INFO é:
name: NAD27(76) / MTM zone 12
ellps: clark66
proj: tmerc
lat_0: 0
lon_0: -81
k: 0.9999
x_0: 304800
y_0: 0
no_defs: defined
init: EPSG:2021

PROJ_INFO do conjunto de dados é:
name: WGS 84 / UTM zone 23N
datum: wgs84
ellps: wgs84
proj: utm
zone: 23
no_defs: defined

ERROR: proj
```

I can only create the raster overriding my projections above the image using flag -o in the parameters, but I don't want to do that. I want to know if I can create the raster using the same image's.

Answer (score 2):

You can import **and reproject** the GeoTIFF file to the current location with `r.import`, or you can create a new location that matches the projection of the file, and then import the file there. You can create the new location with the `target` and `location` options to `r.in.gdal`, or create a new GRASS session: `grass -c landsat-image.tiff <new_location>`.